# Tiny 240v RC Snubber, LC Filter for GFCI outlets

Tags: electrical

What's the tiniest 240v RC Snubber or LC Filter have you used or seen that one can plug into a receptacle outlet like a plug (where the appliance can plug into the LC filter plug unit)?

[image]

My siblings bathroom brand new 240v GFCI receptacle kept tripping on the small black electric fan. They want me to remove the outlet, but I need it as backup to the full house GFCI breakers (in case they fail).

In my experiments before. If I added an LC filter to the GFCI outlets, it no longer trip. But the LC filter I had was huge (a long power strip, not appropriate for bathroom used as it can cause shock).

The LC filter works because an EE explained to me it can flatten the energy of the magnetic field.

This was because even when with ac input put to the load side with ac input open (illustration below). It still tripped (even when the design was not reversible). This means it was not tripping due to leakage current but some kind of capacitive coupling effect (I gave a sample to an EE and he is still analyzing it).

[image]

Comment: Your question would be far more effective if you included the reasons why you believe you need to use an LC filter and reasons why you think you think a smallest size is needed. Applying a down vote in the hopes you can improve this question before others come and vote to close it for reason of "unclear what you are asking).

Comment: done, in full details.

Comment: Nice. Down vote removed.

Comment: You wrote "They want me to remove the outlet" - wouldn't it be easier to remove the small black electric fan?

Comment: It's hot inside the bathroom. What do you replace the fan with? The motor that can nuisance trip GFCI are mostly "shaded pole motor" due to its windings that can cause inductive kickback. Do you know what kind of fan that doesn't use shaded pole motor?  My fridges also have shaded pole motor and it tripped twice a day. But never on Siemens GFCI breakers which never tripped at all on anything.

Comment: The device is faulty. Period. If you think a snubber will fix the device, add it to the device.  But I doubt it.  However, this really feels like a "How do I spend $200 of smart people's time  (including my own) to solve a $10 problem?" question.   And I really dislike those.